# How to add additional data from external API to existing model in the collection?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a basic REST API running locally on a development server with a sqlite DB behind. My model has two properties. Year and title. Based upon those two properties I want to fetch additional data from an external public API through an AJAX call for each model but don't want to store that additional data in my local DB. How can I do that? Overwriting the collection's fetch method?

Improvements for the recursive AJAX call would be appreciated as well...

Thank you

Code:

```
class window.Movie extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: ->
        @fetchData()

    fetchData: ->
        api_url = "api_url"
        api_key = "api_key"
        model   = @
        year    = model.get "year"
        title   = model.get "title"

        $.get "#{api_url}/configuration?api_key=#{api_key}", (data) ->
            model.set "base_url", data.images.base_url

            $.get "#{api_url}/search/movie?api_key=#{api_key}&query=#{title}&include_adult=false&year=#{year}", (data) ->
                q_id = data.results[0].id

                $.get "#{api_url}/movie/#{q_id}?api_key=#{api_key}", (data) ->
                    model.set "poster_path", data.poster_path

class window.Movies extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Movie
    url: "/api/movies"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to decorate your models with additional data from another API. I think the best approach would be to implement your own version of [`Backbone.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync):

> Backbone.sync is the function that Backbone calls every time it attempts to read or save a model to the server. By default, it uses `jQuery.ajax` to make a RESTful JSON request and returns a jqXHR. You can override it in order to use a different persistence strategy, such as WebSockets, XML transport, or Local Storage.
>
> The method signature of Backbone.sync is `sync(method, model, [options])`
>
> - method – the CRUD method (`"create"`, `"read"`, `"update"`, or `"delete"`)
> - model – the model to be saved (or collection to be read)
> - options – success and error callbacks, and all other jQuery request options

Further:

> The sync function may be overriden globally as `Backbone.sync`, or at a finer-grained level, by adding a `sync` function to a Backbone collection or to an individual model.
>
> The default sync handler maps CRUD to REST like so:
>
> - create → POST   `/collection`
> - read → GET   `/collection[/id]`
> - update → PUT   `/collection/id`
> - delete → DELETE   `/collection/id`

So, you should be able to implement a `sync` function which first fetches the data from your API with the default `Backbone.sync`, and then decorates it with the data from the external API.

To handle the three GETs, you could use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), something like:

```
getConfig = (next) ->

  $.get "#{api_url}/configuration?api_key=#{api_key}", next

findMovie = (next) ->

  $.get "#{api_url}/search/movie?api_key=#{api_key}&query=#{title}&include_adult=false&year=#{year}", next

async.parallel [getConfig, findMovie], (err, [config, movie]) ->

  $.get "#{api_url}/movie/#{movie.results[0].id}?api_key=#{api_key}", (data) ->
    model.set "base_url", config.images.base_url
    model.set "poster_path", data.poster_path
```

**Edit:** Another possibility is to simply have another model, say `MovieData`, the URL of which points to this external API instead. Might be a cleaner way to leverage Backbone here, as well.